# Is it possible to retrieve number of departments and the number of employees working in that department if given the location Id

Tags: sql

Is it possible to retrieve the number of departments and the number of employees working in that department if given the location Id? `Location_id` column is in the departments table. Employees and Department share `department_id` column

Cannot get the correct result with this query:

```
select 
    count(E.employee_id), count(D.DEPARTMENT_ID)
from 
    employees e   
join 
    departments d on (e.department_id = d.department_id) 
where
    D.LOCATION_ID = 1700;
```

Comment: can you please provide your sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: DO NOT SHOUT by using all capitals. Please.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need `distinct` when counting the departments:

```
SELECT
    COUNT( E.employee_id )
  , COUNT(DISTINCT d.department_id )
FROM employees e
JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
WHERE d.location_id = 1700;
```

or, you need to group by department:

```
SELECT
    COUNT( E.employee_id )
  , d.department_id
FROM employees e
JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
WHERE d.location_id = 1700
GROUP BY d.department_id;
```